# Best POSIX way to determine if a filesystem is mounted read only

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, posix, readonly

If I have a POSIX system like Linux or Mac OS X, what's the best and most portable way to determine if a path is on a read-only filesystem?  I can think of 4 ways off the top of my head:

- `open(2)` a file with `O_WRONLY` - You would need to come up with a unique filename and also pass in `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL`.  If it fails and you have an errno of `EROFS` then you know it's a read-only filesystem.  This would have the annoying side effect of actually creating a file you didn't care about, but you could `unlink(2)` it immediately after creating it.
- `statvfs(3)` - One of the fields of the returned `struct statvfs` is `f_flag`, and one of the flags is `ST_RDONLY` for a read-only filesystem.  However, the spec for `statvfs(3)` makes it clear that applications cannot depend on any of the fields containing valid information.  It would seem there's a decent possibility `ST_RDONLY` might not be set for a read-only filesystem.
- `access(2)` - If you know the mount point, you can use `access(2)` with the `W_OK` flag as long as you are running as a user who would have write access to the mountpoint.  Ie, either you are root or it was mounted with your UID as a mount parameter.  You would get a return value of -1 and an errno of `EROFS`.
- Parsing `/etc/mtab` or `/proc/mounts` - Doesn't seem portable.  Mac OS X seems to have neither of these, for example.  Even if the system did have `/etc/mtab` I'm not sure the fields are consistent between OSes or if the mount options for read-only (`ro` on Linux) are portable.

Are there other ways I'm missing?  If you needed to know if a filesystem was mounted read-only, how would you do it?

Comment: On the mtab one, if a file system is mounted rw but goes ro afterwards, mtab won't update. /proc/mounts will update correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You could also `popen` the command `mount` and examine the output looking for your file system and seeing if it held the text `" (ro,"`.

But again, that's not necessarily portable.

My option would be to  not worry about whether the file system was mounted read only at all. Just try and create your file and, if it fails, tell the user what the error was. And, of course, give them the option of saving it somewhere else.

You really have to do that sort of thing anyway since, in any scenario where there's even a small gap between testing and doing, you may find the situation changes (probably not to the extent of making an entire file system read only but, who knows, maybe there is (or will be in the future) a file system that allows this).

Comment: Agree in the general case with just writing because of race conditions; this is why access(2) is generally discouraged.  But in my specific case I need to make a policy decision based entirely on whether or not the FS was itself mounted read-only; I don't actually care about writing a file to the FS.

Comment: ```mount``` uses ```/etc/mtab``` which itself might be incorrect if it's on a ro filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

```
utime(path, NULL);
```

If you have write perms, then that will give you ROFS or -- if permitted -- simply update the mtime on the directory, which is basically harmless.

Comment: Basically harmless except perhaps for, say, ... incremental backup programs? :-)